# как session переделать в json?

Tags: python, json

У меня есть папка sessions с файлами .session, мне надо эти файлы преобразовать в json

Также у меня есть код (скопированный с форума), который выдаёт непонятную мне ошибку:
Ссылка на код на форуме - https://qaa-engineer.ru/kak-konvertit-session-tdata-telegram-fajl-v-json/

```
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
import json
import os

session_path = "sessions/abc.session"
output_path = "json"


def convert_session_to_json(session_path, output_path):
    with open(session_path, 'rb') as session_file:
        session_data = session_file.read()
        session_data = session_data.decode('utf-8')



    session_json = {
        'session_data': session_data
    }

    with open(output_path, 'w') as json_file:
        json.dump(session_json, json_file)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    session_path = f'sessions/abc.session'  # замените путь_к_файлу на путь к вашему session/tdata файлу
    output_path = f'json'  # замените путь_к_выходному_файлу на путь, куда вы хотите сохранить результат

    convert_session_to_json(session_path, output_path)
```

Код ошибки:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'TLObject' from partially initialized module 'telethon.tl' (most likely due to a circular import) (F:\pythonProject\test_canverter_tdata\venv\lib\site-packages\telethon\tl\__init__.py)
```

Comment: по сути session файлы это sqlite таблица, так что тебе надо преобразовывать sqlite в json

Comment: FractalIT не подскажите, как?

Comment: я точно не знаю как именно составлен session, только сам факт этого когда то заметил, тут вам уже стоит изучить библиотеку sqlite и состав session`а